# Abort operation if validation fails with validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm validating some data and then performing an operation, example:

```
app.get('/user/makeRider', auth,
    (req, res, next) => {
        req.assert("name", "requierd").notEmpty();
        req.assert("phone", "requierd").notEmpty();
        req.assert("phone", "must be number").isPhone();

        sequelize.Promise.all([
            req.user.obj.addAttribute('name',req.query.name),
            req.user.obj.addAttribute('phone', req.query.phone),
            req.user.obj.addAttribute('rider', 'true')
        ]).then(() => next());

    },render
);
```

If not all data is valid, I want to skip the latter part of the validation and go straight to render. This is a repeated thing in almost every js-file, how can this be done in a nice, consistent way?

Comment: It looks like you never call `req.validationErrors()`. If you don't do that, your asserts are useless.

Comment: I do it in render, and output the errors in a json-object, this is for REST-protocol.

Comment: Well then you can't really check for validation errors anywhere but `render` unless you're willing to move that statement.